# Visual way to add DATATRIGGER in Expression Blend 2013

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, blend, datatrigger

Which is the right procedure to attach a datatrigger to an UI element using expression blend 2013?

If I write datatrigger directly in xaml it works good, but I want to know if is there a "visual way" to do that.

For example, creating a listboxitem style I'm doing something like this:

---

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BoundingBoxTemplate" DataType="{x:Type is:BoundingBoxViewModel}" >
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBorderVisible}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="InsideRectangle" Property="Stroke" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="InsideRectangle" 
                   Width="{Binding Width}" 
                   Height="{Binding Height}" 
                   Fill="Black" 
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

Thank you
Lorenzo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is an example of how you'd do it using the GUI.**

**Consider this Window:**

[image]

The goal in my example is to make the `Stroke` of the `Rectangle` blue when the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property changes to `True`.

For that first we have to add a `ChangePropertyAction` from `Assets` > `Behaviors`.

[image]

Drag and drop it onto a window/template/whatever. I put it into the window:

[image]

Now if you select it you can specify the `Trigger` in `Properties`.

[image]

I set the `TriggerType` to `DataTrigger`, the `Binding` to `Checkbox.IsChecked` and the required value for the `Trigger` to `True`.

Next, I specify the `Value` that should be changed when the `Trigger` fires.

[image]

I set the `Target` to the `Rectangle`, specified `Stroke` as `PropertyName` and set the `Value` this property should get when the `Trigger` fires to blue.

**If I now start the application this is the result when I check the `CheckBox`:**

[image]